# Sequence convergence.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that if the sequence $\{a_n^3\}_{n = 0}^{\infty}$ converges then $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ convervges.

I've started with $\forall \epsilon > 0 \: \exists N \in \mathbb{Z}_{+} \: s.t. \: \forall n > N, |a_n^3 -L^3| < \epsilon$ and $|a_n - L||a_n^2 + La_n + L^2| $ and we know $|a_n -L| < \epsilon$ but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: continuous function

Answer (score 1):

This follows immediately since the map

$$f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}:x\mapsto x^{1/3}$$is continuous and continuous functions preserve convergent sequences (if $x_n\to x$, then $f(x_n)\to f(x)$).

Comment: how does this prove that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent?  if $\{a_n^3\}$ is a continuous function. Since if it was $\{a_n^2\}$ convergent this does not imply a_n is convergent.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but I would like to prove it with the definition of sequence/convergence.

Comment: Ye$a_n^2$ convergent implies $|a_n|$ convergent by the same argument.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above mention that $x\mapsto x^{1/3}$ is continuous, but at this stage in the course, I'm not sure that rigorously proving this is easy. Sure, if you assume this fact and some theorems down the road, the proof is trivial. To prove it directly:

Assume $a_n^3 \to L^3$. We want to show $a_n \to L$. For a given $\epsilon>0$, write 
$$
-\epsilon<a_n-L<\epsilon \implies L-\epsilon<a_n<L+\epsilon\implies (L-\epsilon)^3<a_n^3<(L+\epsilon)^3
$$
so
$$
(L-\epsilon)^3-L^3<a_n^3-L^3<(L+\epsilon)^3-L^3
$$
Choose $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,$ the last inequality holds. Then for the same $n$, we have $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. By the way, this is essentially the proof that $x \mapsto x^{1/3}$ is continuous.

Technically, you should show why the last inequality holds if $a_n^3 \to L^3$.